# Count specific date in date range in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, count, date-range

I want to ask you how can I get count of specific date (DD-MON) from date range (DD-MON-YY) from Oracle SQL?
This is what I have:

```
MEMBERS    INSTALL_D   DOB      SYSDATE
6934109    22-FEB-12   18-NOV   09-JAN-17
6934109    22-FEB-12   13-JUN   09-JAN-17
6934109    22-FEB-12   12-AUG   09-JAN-17
6934109    22-FEB-12   24-OCT   09-JAN-17
6934109    22-FEB-12   04-FEB   09-JAN-17
```

I want count DOB from range of dates INSTALL_D and SYSDATE. Let's say that the

1. row with 18-NOV is appear 5 times,
2. row with 13-JUN is appear 5 times,
3. row with 12-AUG is appear 5 times,
4. row with 24-OCT is apeear 5 times

and the last one is only 4 times.

so, the result should be like:

```
MEMBERS   INSTALL_D   DOB      SYSDATE    COUNT(DOB)
6934109    22-FEB-12   18-NOV   09-JAN-17  5
6934109    22-FEB-12   13-JUN   09-JAN-17  5
6934109    22-FEB-12   12-AUG   09-JAN-17  5
6934109    22-FEB-12   24-OCT   09-JAN-17  5
6934109    22-FEB-12   04-FEB   09-JAN-17  4
```

I tried used MONTHS_BETWEEN function but this is not what I want to get.

EDIT:
I will be more specific. I used this query to get the first table above:
`select B0022HOME_NO as Members,
B0022INSTALLDATE as INSTALL_DATE,
to_char(to_date (encryption.decrypt(a.B0031MEMDATEOFBIRT),'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON')as DOB,
SYSDATE 
from BT0022, BT0031 a
where B0022HOME_NO=a.B003101HOME_NO and BT0022.B0022HOME_NO=6934109;`

`INSTALL_D` is day of instalation, which is in this example 22-FEB-12 
`DOB` is birthday of member. Only day and month (DD-MON) 
`SYSDATE` is for actual date.

Let's say, if the sysdate would be 18-NOV-12 and INSTALL_D is 22-FEB-12 and DOB of member is  18-NOV, that's mean that the DOB is occur once in this range of date. 
In example: INSTALL_D 22-FEB-12 and SYSDATE 09-JAN-17 is DOB of 18-NOV occur 5 times, but if the SYSDATE will be 18-NOV-17, it will be 6 times. And that's it what I asked you about count(DOB) in date range.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Column data types? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: INSTALL_D column is DATE type and DOB is varchar2. DBMS is Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bit

Comment: Severa problems with this setup. Why is "SYSDATE" a column in this table? SYSDATE is a system function, its value is calculated on the fly, it is not stored in tables. Did you mean to use SYSDATE (but not have a column in the table for it), or did you mean to use a stored date, which shouldn't be called "SYSDATE"? Then - did you mean to change the MEMBERS column so you don't have the same value in all the rows? (I don't suppose the same member has different birth dates). Also, why is the DOB stored as VARCHAR2, instead of being a date (INCLUDING the year)?

Comment: SYSDATE doesn't have to be there. I mean the first option: not have a column in the table, just use the SYSDATE. I don't know why DOB stored as VARCHAR2. I began using this system with this type. I cannot change it. In this particular example I don't need to know YEAR of DOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way that will hopefully work with dob's that occur on leap years:

(N.b. I have assumed all your dates are stored as DATEs, meaning that your dob column has years. If that isn't the case, then a) why aren't you storing the year with the dob? and b) you'll have to update my query to convert the string into a suitable format for the comparison)

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 6934109 members, to_date('22/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('18/11/1969', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934109 members, to_date('22/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('13/06/1991', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934109 members, to_date('22/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('12/08/1982', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934109 members, to_date('22/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('24/10/1963', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934109 members, to_date('22/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('04/02/1975', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934110 members, to_date('28/02/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('29/02/1976', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934110 members, to_date('29/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('01/03/1975', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934111 members, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('12/01/1957', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934111 members, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('02/01/1980', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934112 members, to_date('01/03/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('29/02/1976', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6934112 members, to_date('29/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') install_d, to_date('29/02/1976', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dob FROM dual)
SELECT members,
       install_d,
       dob,
       SYSDATE,
       date_of_first_year,
       date_of_latest_year,
       months_between(date_of_latest_year, date_of_first_year)/12 + 1 count_birthdays
FROM   (SELECT members,
               install_d,
               dob,
               SYSDATE,
               CASE WHEN to_char(dob, 'mmdd') < to_char(install_d, 'mmdd') THEN
                         trunc(add_months(install_d, 12), 'yyyy')
                    ELSE trunc(install_d, 'yyyy')
               END date_of_first_year,
               CASE WHEN to_char(dob, 'mmdd') <= to_char(SYSDATE, 'mmdd') THEN
                         trunc(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')
                    ELSE add_months(trunc(SYSDATE, 'yyyy'), -12)
               END date_of_latest_year
        FROM   sample_data);

   MEMBERS INSTALL_D   DOB         SYSDATE     DATE_OF_FIRST_YEAR DATE_OF_LATEST_YEAR COUNT_BIRTHDAYS
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------ ------------------- ---------------
   6934109 22/02/2012  18/11/1969  09/01/2017  01/01/2012         01/01/2016                        5
   6934109 22/02/2012  13/06/1991  09/01/2017  01/01/2012         01/01/2016                        5
   6934109 22/02/2012  12/08/1982  09/01/2017  01/01/2012         01/01/2016                        5
   6934109 22/02/2012  24/10/1963  09/01/2017  01/01/2012         01/01/2016                        5
   6934109 22/02/2012  04/02/1975  09/01/2017  01/01/2013         01/01/2016                        4
   6934110 28/02/2011  29/02/1976  09/01/2017  01/01/2011         01/01/2016                        6
   6934110 29/02/2012  01/03/1975  09/01/2017  01/01/2012         01/01/2016                        5
   6934111 01/01/2017  12/01/1957  09/01/2017  01/01/2017         01/01/2016                        0
   6934111 01/01/2017  02/01/1980  09/01/2017  01/01/2017         01/01/2017                        1
   6934112 01/03/2011  29/02/1976  09/01/2017  01/01/2012         01/01/2016                        5
   6934112 29/02/2012  29/02/1976  09/01/2017  01/01/2012         01/01/2016                        5
```

The only fly in the ointment occurs if you want a dob of 29th Feb to match to 1st of March on non-leap years.

My query above doesn't have that logic in it, but you could always add in a check to compare the last day of February in the install_d and sysdate years, and if it's 28th, then change a dob of '29/02' to '01/03' before doing that comparison. (I.e. compare install_d of 29/02/2012 with dob = 29/02 as 2012 is a leap year. You don't need to compare the sysdate, since 0301 >= 0229 and 0228 < 0229, regardess of whether the sysdate is a leap year or not.)

Comment: Hmm... interesting topic I hadn't thought about before. The dob of a "leaper" has legal meaning (for example, when is a "leaper" allowed to get a driver's license?) I always assumed it'd be Feb. 28 in non-leap years, but Wikipedia shows that in many jurisdictions it's March 1. That doesn't make much sense to me; leap day is Feb. 29 because it was invented when the calendar year was still starting on March 1. (SEPTember was the 7th month, OCTober the 8th etc.) So Feb. 29 is also the last day of a year, not just a month. When it's not there, why move the anniversary to a different year?

Comment: @mathguy I always assumed 1st March because: (last day of February) + 366 days = 29th Feb (in a leap year) or 1st March (in a non-leap year)

Comment: `add_months()`, for example, doesn't use that logic. It matches month-end to month-end, regardless of 30 or 31. Since we must be "off by one day", it would make more sense to me if at least the month (and the pre-Julius Caesar calendar year) were preserved, rather than moving the date into the next month and "year". But, of course, what makes sense to me is irrelevant; if the OP is using this for anything other than personal amusement, he should clarify what the business (perhaps legal) requirement is. Interesting topic either way!

Comment: @Boneist: This is what I am looking for. Yes, the problem with leap year. I have one query which is solving this problem:

Comment: `case when to_char(to_date (encryption.decrypt(B0031MEMDATEOFBIRT),'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD.MM') like '29.02%' then
      floor(abs(MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date(Sysdate,'DD.MM.YY'),to_date(to_char(to_date (encryption.decrypt(a.B0031MEMDATEOFBIRT),'DD-MON-YYYY')- interval '1' day,'DD.MM')||'.'||to_char(to_date (B0022INSTALLDATE,'DD-MM-YY'),'YY'),'DD.MM.YY'))/12))*20
else  floor(abs(MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date(Sysdate,'DD.MM.YY'),to_date(to_char(to_date (encryption.decrypt(a.B0031MEMDATEOFBIRT),'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD.MM')||'.'||to_char(to_date (B0022INSTALLDATE,'DD-MM-YY'),'YY'),'DD.MM.YY'))/12))*20 end`

Answer (score 0):

You could group by date segments, it's not the prettiest thing but will work. e.g.

```
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(mm, dob) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, dob) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

you could also place that in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (group by should work)

```
SELECT MEMBERS,INSTALL_D,DOB,SYSDATE,Count(DOB) FROM table_name GROUP BY  DOB ,MEMBERS,INSTALL_D  ,SYSDATE
```